# MariaDB incorrect dates

Tags: date, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table. One column has many records. However, the date is sometimes formatted incorrectly. So 1998-00-00 or 2024-00-00.
Why does mysql allow this and how can I find or correct/delete these records?

Comment: What is the column data type?

Comment: If you're using a proper `DATE` column, which you *really* should be, this is effectively impossible. If not you'll need to clean up your data, then `ALTER TABLE` to switch it over. This of course presumes you've **made backups**.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Check [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) in `sql_mode`.

Comment: I am using mariaDB 10.6 and it is possible to save this date. I am importing this from another db structure where this error is already included.

INSERT INTO `series` SELECT isbn, pubdate,......

It is a DATE field. Maybe I can use the 'no_zero_in_date', but I don't know how.

Comment: However, this workaround is not optimal

Comment: I edited to correct your title and tags, since you said you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products. MariaDB started as  fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed enough since then that we should now think of them as totally different, incompatible products.

Comment: you can do `select @@sql_mode` to see if NO_ZERO_IN_DATE is enabled.   if you want to prevent inserts of these dates set sql_mode in a configuration file.  (in mysql, but *not* in mariadb, you can set it permanently with `set persist sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','')`)

Comment: Note `set persist` isn't supported in MariaDB.

Comment: re finding the records, that's just `month(datecol)=0 or day(datecol=0)`